# UTF-8 in Qt Creator on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, utf-8, keyboard

I have a problem with Qt Creator in Linux.
While I am using 2 languages (English + Persian) for my program, I need to switch between them, but there is a problem in Qt Creator, and it is just when I am using it to code in Linux (Qt Creator in Windows works fine).

Switching the keyboard input does not work while I am coding in Qt ,the icon in my menu bar will change to "FA" from "EN" and the other way around but Qt keeps using the keyboard input from when I opened Qt.

For example when I open Qt while my keyboard input (in menu bar) is set to "FA" , Qt only gets Persian chars even when the keyboard input is set to "EN" later when Qt is already open and when i open Qt while my keyboard input is set on EN, Qt only and only gets EN chars and will not change by my switching

So basically I have to open and close Qt every time i want to switch keyboard input , or I just have to write my Persian strings in g-edit and then copy them to my code in Qt

I did take a look in "default-encoding" in "options" and changed the "System" to "UTF-8" then clicked on OK (No errors), but it did not make any difference and every time I return to option, I see the encoding is set to "System" again, it looks like Qt is rejecting (this does not happen when I set the "default-encoding" to UTF-16 or 32 or ... )

I am sure that the proper keyboard inputs are installed correctly because it works in Firefox or g-edit, I don't have this problem in Qt Creator on Windows, just on Linux

Comment: It looks like you have a program you call Qt. It isn't clear what this program is exactly. Qt is a name of a suite of libraries. Do you mean Qt Designer perhaps?

Comment: Qt creator 5.9 """""""

Comment: The last release of Qt Creator is 4.4.1, released a few days ago. Qt Creator 5.9 does not exist. Qt 5.9 exists. [It's a known problem in Qt Creator, caused by a bug in Qt itaelf](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-17650). You may want to upgrade to tge newest versions of Qt and Creator.

Comment: ok . now i get it , there was a mixup . sorry. i am using the last version . 5.9.2 package from Qt downdoal page , so i guess its copy and paste for me

Comment: I'm using Qt Creator 4.3.1 Based on Qt 5.9.0 when I change keyboard layout everything is fine.
I'm using kubuntu kde plasma 5.9.4. You may fix your problem with sudo apt-get update or upgrade commands

Comment: apt-get is only available on Ubuntu and derivatives

Comment: i will try this , i haven't update in ages , @piedpiper i haven't mention earlier but i am using Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

This was a known [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-17650) in Qt. This is fixed in Qt Creator 4.4.1 using Qt 5.9.2